# Only allow column to have true once for each id?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
ID | genre_id | is_best_in_genre | movie_name
--------------------------------
1  | 3        | 0                | Hateful Eight
2  | 3        | 0                | Django Unchained
2  | 3        | 1                | Inglorious B
2  | 3        | 0                | Once Upon A Time in Hollywood
```

`is_best_in_genre` can only be true (1) once for every `genre_id`. There can only be 1 best movie in each genre.
How would I make a constraint such as this?

Comment: I think you will have to enforce this via a trigger.

Comment: You can build the logic into the query itself

Answer (score 2):

Alternative idea:

The more proper, normalized way to handle this is probably to make a separate 'best_in_genre' table with a unique constraint on `genre_id`.

This is also easier to update, because you're not required to make sure that everything gets 0'd when selecting a new 'best'.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach might be to "move" the column `is_best_in_genre` to a separate (joined) table. A simple table with two columns could do the job:

```
CREATE TABLE best (
  idmovie int,
  idgenre int,
  PRIMARY KEY (idgenre))
```

This would need to be joined with the original table like:

```
SELECT m.*, CASE b.idmovie>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END best_in_genre
FROM movietable m
LEFT JOIN best b ON idmovie=id AND idgenre=genre_id
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint in the table `best` will make sure that each genre can only appear once.